# Correct way to get all information from BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm build an app Android that should to connect to a BLE device every 5 second (for example). Now I want to know what is the correct way to do this. I'm thinkg an app that in onCreate method call a Service. This service, have in your onCreate e timer that call every 5 second some method. But I don't know if this is a correct way. Can we help me ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for... For example if this is always the same device you'd better keeping it connected and not doing connect/disconnect every 5 secs...

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to use [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html)

To download this library use

```
dependencies {
     compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'
   }
```

Here is the answer for [How do I customize the background scan rate?](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the SCAN PERIOD, is to set the frequency of the call of BLE Device ?

Comment: It will scan with the time interval as your requirement. If this answer helps you please accept the answer :P

Comment: I don't know how can I set this SCAN_PERIOD. Can we explain me ?

Comment: which library are you using? show me the link to that library.

Comment: I don't use never library. If there is some library to do this plese link me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166676/discussion-between-vikash-parajuli-and-bircastri).

Comment: can we continue the discussion in chat ?